# set json = true for jquery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using the jquery cookie plug in
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

when I try to set json = true by doing 
var jq=jQuery
jq.cookie.json = true;

I got an syntax Error at line 55 in cookie.js file

```
var decode = config.raw ? raw : decoded;
        var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
        for (var i = 0, l = cookies.length; i < l; i++) {
            var parts = cookies[i].split('=');
            if (decode(parts.shift()) === key) {
                var cookie = decode(parts.join('='));
                return config.json ? JSON.parse(cookie) : cookie; /line 55
```

Anyone having the same issue as me?

Answer (score 0):

The value must be set to true when you are storing cookie value as json string. JSON.parse fails if the passed string is not in valid json format.